# getting input for structure from function

Tags: c

I was trying to send a structure to a function and fill out the structure with the right value in the function and then display the value in main, but it was not is not working when i run it.**(i cant use pointer functions).**

```
 struct inventory{
                char name[20];
                int number;

                   };
void function(struct inventory items);
int main()
{
int x,y,z;
 struct inventory items;
function(items);
printf("\nam in main\n");
printf("\n%s\t",(items).name);
printf(" %i\t",(items).number); 
getch();    

    }
   void function(struct inventory items)
    {
printf(" enter the item name\n ");
scanf(" %s ",&(items).name );
printf(" enter the number of items\n ");
scanf("%i",&(items).number );
    }
```

(ie: i am not allowed to use pointer function )  how can i display the name and the number without pointer.

Comment: the error that i am getting is ^^The variable 'items' is being used without being initialized.^^

Comment: Are you not allowed to use pointer functions or are you not allowed to use pointers in functions ?

Comment: void function (struct inventory * );

Comment: it should be by value not by reference

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Comment: sorry i am new to this website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct inventory
{
    char name[20];
    int number;
};

struct inventory function();

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    struct inventory items;
    items=function();
    printf("\nam in main\n");
    printf("\n%s\t",(items).name);
    printf(" %d\t",(items).number); 
    getch();
}

struct inventory function()
{
    struct inventory items;
    printf(" enter the item name\n ");
    scanf(" %s ",&items.name );
    printf(" enter the number of items\n ");
    scanf("%d",&items.number );
    return items;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error i do not know why

Comment: It seems working fine for me. In which line are you getting the error? Also which compiler are you using ?

Comment: i am using c compiler and the error is at items=function(items); the error is saying  The variable 'items' is being used without being initialized.

Comment: Is the compiler name "c compiler" ? Are you sure ?

Comment: i am using visual basic c++. but i am using it by creating .c file

Answer (score 0):

you can return the structure reference from the function, considor the code given below

```
 struct inventory{
  char name[20];
  int number;
 };

struct inventory function(struct inventory items);

int main()
{
 int x,y,z;
 struct inventory items,ret_itm;
 ret_itm=function(items);
 printf("\nam in main\n");
 printf("\n%s\t",(ret_itm).name);
 printf(" %i\t",(ret_itm).number); 
 getch();    

}

struct inventory function(struct inventory items)
{
  printf(" enter the item name\n ");
  scanf(" %s ",&(items).name );
  printf(" enter the number of items\n ");
  scanf("%i",&(items).number );
  return items;
}
```